# Where is it possible to download a DEM for the Romanian east carpathians?

Tags: data, dem, romania

I'm quite new to GIS and have only done a few small tasks for Projects at University and the required data has always been provided. I am now struggling to find the specific DEM I need. Also other terrain data such as presence of glaciers (or former glaciers) and river networks would be useful.

Comment: have you tried SRTM ?

Comment: Answers to this question might help: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/where-to-download-free-elevation-data-for-europe