# Free Digital Elevation (Terrain) Model of Europe or Germany

Tags: data, dem, elevation, terrain, 3d-model

Is there any free (or not expensive) source of Digital elevation model of Europe or Germany with the resolution of 10 meters or better and vertical accuracy of +-5m or better?

Comment: You might want to look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/where-to-download-free-elevation-data-for-europe

Comment: I have similar reqiurements and have chosen GMTED2010 from http://edcintl.cr.usgs.gov/downloads/sciweb1/shared/topo/downloads/GMTED/GMTED_Metadata/GMTED2010_Spatial_Metadata.zip The data are in ShapeFile format

Comment: If this may be open data, then I think it is a question better asked at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 5):

For Germany you can order the **DGM10** from the [Federal Agency for Cartogrpahy](http://www.bkg.bund.de/).

The [Official Elevation Datasets](http://www.bkg.bund.de/nn_171762/EN/FederalOffice/Products/Geo-Data/Digital-Terrain-Models/DGM-Germany/DGMGermany__node.html__nnn=true#doc171766bodyText1) are available in 10 m to 1000 m spatial resolution with a height accuracy of 0.5-2 m.

Comment: It lists a € 291000 price tag for me (plus VAT plus shipping costs). I'd not call that "free (or non-expensive)".

Comment: 5 years ago you could order it free. I can still find some provinces (Bundesländer) offering it free. But you are right - the complete Germany DGM10 is not offered free anymore.